# Chrome Extension - Read Local Text File

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, fetch

Hi I have a Chrome Extension and I would like for it to be able to read local text files.

I remember years ago, Chrome supports `chrome.fileSystem`. However, this has since been deprecated.

The closest thing I could get to reading any sort of file was this code below:

```
async function getFile(){
    //Only able to read files in the extension folder. 
    //not allowed on local resources
    var url = chrome.runtime.getURL('manifest.json');
    var response = await fetch(url);
    var data = await response.json();
    console.log(data);
}
```

However, when I tried to `fetch()` from a url like `C:\\Users\\user\\Desktop\\TestFolder\\test.txt`, I would get the following error message:

```
Not allowed to load local resource
```

I have also added the `"storage"` permissions in my `manifest.json` correctly I believe.

```
"permissions" : [
   "cookies", "tabs",
   "webNavigation",
   "storage",
   "http://*/",
   "https://*/"
    ]
```

Is there a newer version of `chrome.fileSystem` or any other way I could use to read a text file stored locally?

My Chrome Version is : `100.0.4896.75`

Comment: 1) `storage` permission is unrelated, 2) chrome.fileSystem is only for chrome apps, not extensions, 3) to use `fetch` with local files you need to use a `file://` URL and tick the file access checkbox in your extension's details in chrome://extensions page.

Comment: @wOxxOm Thanks for the clarifications. Is there anyway I do not have to tick the checkbox in the chrome://extensions page? Is there some way i could do it programmatically? Perhaps by adding some permissions in the `manifest.json` ?

Comment: Use the [new File System API](https://web.dev/file-system-access/).

Comment: @wOxxOm What i'm doing is having the extension open up a configuration file that is always constantly changing by another program. I can't have the user to choose which file to open. :/

Comment: See the documentation for this API: choosing is only needed once, then you can read the file periodically. You can also store the handle in IndexedDB and reuse it afterwards.